# Confusion regarding the equality of functions

Tags: functions

Suppose $f(x)=\frac{x-5}{x^2-25}$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x+5}$

I know that a function can be though of as a set of ordered pairs and I know that two sets are equal if and only if they contain the same elements.

Since the domain of $f$ is $(-\infty,-5)\cup(-5,5)\cup(5,\infty)$ and the domain of $g$ is $(-\infty,-5)\cup(-5,\infty)$, clearly $f(x)\not=g(x)$.

But also $f(x)=\frac{x-5}{x^2-25}=\frac{x-5}{(x+5)(x-5)}=\frac{1}{x+5}=g(x)$.

What am I missing here? I must be missing something obvious but I'm running around in circles.

Comment: They have different domains but they coincide on  the intersection of their domains.

Comment: And this, ladies and gentlemen, is the reason, why one always has to denote the domain and codomain of functions, instead of writing their defining assignments only...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chain of equalities

> $f(x)=\frac{x-5}{x^2-25}=\frac{x-5}{(x+5)(x-5)}=\frac{1}{x+5}=g(x)$

only holds for $x\neq -5,5$. The first three expressions don't make sense otherwise. Indeed, both functions coincide in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-5,5\}=(-\infty,-5)\cup(-5,5)\cup(5,\infty)$.